# Powershell string variable substitution

Tags: string, powershell

I am quite familiar with bash's ability to substitute parts of strings in a regex-ish fashion using braces. E.g.:

```bsh
a = "Hello, World!"
echo "${a/World/Nancy}"
```

The above will print "Hello, Nancy!" Does powershell have the ability to do substring-subtitution in this way, or is there an equivalent alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell Replace Characters in a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157036/powershell-replace-characters-in-a-string). There are also many [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+string+replace) of this on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-replace` operator (supports regex):

```
$a = "Hello, World!"
$a -replace "World","Nancy"
```